# How to check if a file with partial name exists in GCS bucket in Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud

I'm trying to write a Python code which will check for a particular file in a folder of Cloud storage bucket and if the file exists then it has to enter the loop. Otherwise exit the loop. File name I want to check is a daily incremental file which starts with "DL_Ticket_".
Actual file name is like : DL_Ticket_merged_20220406201501.csv
Filepath is like : gs://standard/inbound/DL_Ticket_merged_20220406201501.csv
For this functionality I've written code as shown below.

```
from google.cloud import storage
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import time
def df_load_function(file, context):
   name = 'DL_Ticket_'   
   storage_client = storage.Client()
   bucket_name = 'standard'
   bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
   stats = storage.Blob(bucket=bucket, name="inbound/DL_Ticket_").exists(storage_client)
   print(stats)
   if stats == True:
      #my code 
   else: 
      exit()
```

With the above code, I'm always getting False even though the file exists in the bucket.
I'm implementing this code in Cloud Function of GCP. No errors while deploying the code. Can someone please help me in achieving this.
Code using list_blobs with prefix :

```
from google.cloud import storage
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import time
import os

def mv_blob(bucket_name, blob_name):
 client = storage.Client()
 bucket_name = "standard"
 bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)
 blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix='inbound/DL_Ticket_'))
 for blob in blobs:
  blob_name = blob.name
  print("{}.".format(blob_name))
  if blob_name != '':
    def df_load_function(file, context):
        filesnames = [
            'DL_Customer_',
            'DL_RegisteredProducts_',
            'DL_Ticket_'
            ]

        for i in filesnames:
            if 'inbound/{}'.format(i) in file['name']:
                print("Processing file: {filename}".format(filename=file['name']))

                project = 'nonprod'
                inputfile = 'gs://standard/inbound/' + file['name']
                job = 'df_load_wave1_{}'.format(i)
                template = 'gs://standard/template/df_load_wave1_{}'.format(i)
                location = 'asia-south1'
           
                dataflow = build('dataflow', 'v1b3', cache_discovery=False)
                request = dataflow.projects().locations().templates().launch(
                    projectId=project,
                    gcsPath=template,
                    location=location,
                    body={
                        'jobName': job,
                        "environment": {
                        "workerZone": "asia-south1-a"
                    }
                    }
                )

            # Execute the dataflowjob
                response = request.execute()
            
                job_id = response["job"]["id"]
```

Comment: Rewrite your code to list the objects (list_blobs) setting the prefix to the object starting string.

Comment: I actually tried using list_blobs with prefix. But getting the error "AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'list_blobs'". I've added my code using list_blobs in the question.

Comment: Double check which SDK version you are using. Here is a link to the API for **list_blobs()** https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/buckets.html You are also importing two different libraries. Why are you importing **googleapiclient.discovery.build**?  Something is broken/misconfigured with your code or the SDK is setup incorrectly.

Comment: I've modified my code and even now its not throwing any error but the function "df_load_function" is not being executed even though the if condition satisfies (when DL_Ticket file is present). Instead of "df_load_function" function if I give any print statement then it is printing whatever I give. I'm not understanding why the function is not running ?

Comment: 1) using **bucket.list_blobs() is deprecated. Instead, use **client.list_blocbs(bucket_name, prefix=xxx) Retry with that change. 2)  What do you get back if you change the prefix to **inbound/**? 3) Please remove code that is not related to the problem you are trying to solve.